# How can I change the number of items displayed on a page? (Oracle Apex 21.1)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

How can I change the number of items displayed on a page in Interactive grid?

When execute a SQL query, it return 14 records. And all of them are displayed on the first page. I want to display 5 items on each page.
Can this problem be solved by changing any settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- navigate to interactive grid's **Attributes**
- under the "Pagination" property, set

  - Type: **Page**

    - because, if it is set to "Scroll" - which is the default - you can't do what you want
- run the page
- go to the "Actions" button >> Format >> **Rows per page**

  - choose value you want (`5`, right?)

Comment: Thank you for giving me the answer every time! But I can not find the "Action" button on Attributes tab.
Is that the button has some kind of graphic on it?

Comment: Don't skip steps. I said that you should **run** the page, and then access the **Actions** button. It is not in Page Designer, it is in *runtime* window.

Comment: I'm sorry. But I couldn't find the Actions button when I tried "Save and Run Page (Alt+F8)".
I was open the "Pages" tab on the "Page Finder" window, I saw "Actions" button there. But I think that button is different from the "Actions" button you are talking about it. Or it was?

Comment: are you sure it's interactive report? if no, classic reports page doesn't have ACTION button. if yes, check ATTRIBUTE tab on your interactive report section and switch on INCLUDE SEARCH BAR setting

Comment: If you don't see the "Actions" button when you run the page, then go back to Page Designer, navigate to Interactive Grid's "Attributes", scroll down to "Toolbar" and enable its "Show" property. New properties will then be visible; one of them is "Actions menu" - make sure it is checked.

Comment: Great!! 
The toolbar was in the way, so I removed it. You've been wonderful in patiently explaining things to me :D

Comment: Cool, I'm glad you made it work!